# If $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $h$ is an affine map, what does $h^{-1}(x_0 - A)$ mean?

Tags: measure-theory, notation

I am reading a book, and it suddenly says:

> A distribution $\nu$ is symmetric around a point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ if $h(\nu) = \nu$ where $h$ is the affine map given by $h(x) = 2x_0 - x$. As $h^{-1}(x_0 - A) = x_0 + A$ for $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ ...

What does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

The affine map $h$ is invertible, with inverse $h^{-1}(x) = h(x)$. So $$h^{-1}(x_0 - A) = h(x_0 - A) = 2x_0 - (x_0 - A) = x_0 + A.$$

---

**Added Later:** The question has been edited so that $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ rather than $A \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now $x_0 - A$ denotes the set $\{x_0 - a \mid a \in A\}$ and $x_0 + A$ denotes the set $\{x_0 + a \mid a \in A\}$. Given a function $f : X \to Y$, and a subset $S \subset X$, then $f(S)$ denotes the subset $\{f(s) \mid s \in S\}$ of $Y$. So,

$$h^{-1}(x_0 - A) = \{h^{-1}(x_0 - a) \mid a \in A\} = \{h(x_0 - a) \mid a \in A\} = \{x_0 + a \mid a \in A\} = x_0 + A.$$

Comment: What is $x_ 0 - A$? Some sort of translation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If $A > 0$, $x_0 - A$ is $A$ units to the left of $x_0$ on the real number line. If $A < 0$, $x_0 - A$ is $|A|$ units to the right of $x_0$ on the real number line.

Comment: $x_0+A$ is a frequently used shortcut for $\{x | \exists_{a\in A}x=a+x_0\}$

Comment: I made a mistake in my original post. It actually says $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ in the book. Of course if $A$ is just an number (like I wrote it), then this makes perfect sense. But the book says $A$ is a set.

Comment: Then it is a translation of each element of $A$ by $x_0$ as Gyro Gearloose points out in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the inverse of $h(x)$.  Call it $y$:

$$y = 2x_0 - x \to x = 2x_0 - y = h^{-1}(y)$$
$$h^{-1}(x_0 - A) = 2x_0 - (x_0 - A) = x_0 + A.$$